# exit trap in dash vs ksh and bash

Tags: bash, ksh, trap, dash

Here's a simple script that sets up a temp dir in the current dir and a trap to delete it on exit.

```
#filename: script   
set -x  
trap 'rm -rf "$d"' exit
d=`TMPDIR=$PWD mktemp -d`
"$@"
```

If I do `ksh script sleep 100` or `bash script sleep 100` and interrupt it with, `C-C`, the trap gets executed and the directory is deleted.
It doesn't work with `dash`. Why? Is this a bug or intended behavior?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`zsh`, `pdksh` (though not recent versions of `mksh` derived from that), `yash`, the Bourne shell behave like `dash`.

Only `bash`, `ksh88`, `ksh93` and `mksh` behave otherwise.

The POSIX spec is not clear on what should be the correct behaviour, but there's nothing in there that says that the shell is allowed to override the default handler for the `SIGINT` (or other) signal.

It says `EXIT` trap action should be evaluated when `exit` is invoked, but AFAICT, it doesn't even say for instance if it should be evaluated when the shell exits as the result of `set -e` or `set -u` or error conditions like syntax errors or failing special builtins.

To be able to run `EXIT` trap upon reception of a signal, the shell would need to install a handler on that signal.

That's what `ksh`, `mksh` and `bash` do, but the list of signals they handle is different between all three implementations. The only signals common between all 3 seem to be `INT`, `QUIT`, `TERM`, `ALRM` and `HUP`.

If you want the `EXIT` trap to be run upon some signals, the portable way would be to handle those signals yourself:

```
trap 'exit 1' INT HUP QUIT TERM ALRM USR1
trap 'cleanup' EXIT
```

That approach however doesn't work with `zsh`, which doesn't run `EXIT` trap if `exit` is called from a trap handler.

It also fails to report your death-by-signal to your parent.

So instead, you could do:

```
for sig in INT QUIT HUP TERM ALRM USR1; do
  trap "
    cleanup
    trap - $sig EXIT
    kill -s $sig "'"$$"' "$sig"
done
trap cleanup EXIT
```

Now, beware though that if more signals arrive while you're executing `cleanup`, `cleanup` may be run again. You may want to make sure your `cleanup` works correctly if invoked several times and/or ignore signals during its execution.

Comment: `zsh` only behave like `dash` in non-interactive session, it does the same as `bash` and `ksh` in interactive session.

Comment: Nice solution! If I understand it correctly then it even preserves the special exit status codes of the different signals.

Comment: Stéphane, is a process killing itself with the received signal (`kill -s $sig "'"$$"' "$sig"` above) a best practice in general, or is it only applicable with `SIGINT` (as seen at section 5 at [SignalTrap](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap) )

Comment: @iruvar, it's especially important for SIGINT and SIGQUIT as otherwise you'll have troubles if your script is called from a shell that implements that "wait and cooperative exit" approach discussed as that page (which I've amended slightly), but it's a good idea to do it as well for other signals if only to report to your parent that you have been killed.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What is the purpose of the trailing `EXIT` in `trap - $sig EXIT` line? It is the only point where your answer diverges from the wooledge bash guide

Comment: @HaroldFischer, that resets the EXIT trap which avoids `cleanup` being run twice upon signal delivery for shells like mksh or ksh93.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "You may want to make sure your cleanup works correctly if invoked several times and/or ignore signals during its execution." How might I make `cleanup` ignore signals during it's execution? Would this need to be implemented inside the trap that calls `cleanup` or within `cleanup` itself?

Comment: "That approach however doesn't work with zsh, which doesn't run the EXIT trap if exit is called from a trap handler." In contradiction zsh 5.7.1 seems to run EXIT trap, but dash 0.5.10.2-6 does not, if `-e` is used.

Comment: Thanks @jarno, yes it looks like it changed in newer versions of zsh. Do you know which version introduced the change?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Why do you use single quoting in the kill command?

Comment: @jarno, so `"$$"` be passed literally to the *`trap`* command so the code of the trap be something like `cleanup; trap - INT EXIT; kill -s INT "$$"`

Comment: I think it is unneeded because the value of `$$` does not change within the script, if I have understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, the code of the trap could be `cleanup; trap - INT EXIT; kill -s INT 1234` (where 1234 is the value of $$ at the time `trap` was invoked and as you say shouldn't change). While both are equally valid, the output of `trap` in the former case is better as it conveys the intention and can be reused in a context where $$ is different.

Comment: BTW, if you called a script in a wrapper script how would you test death-by-signal of the script in the wrapper script a.k.a parent?

Comment: @jarno, depends what language the wrapper script is written in. For instance, many shells can't distinguish a death by signal 1 from a exit(129). See [Default exit code when process is terminated?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/99134)

Comment: Oh, so by the exit code. I thought the signal would propagate to the caller so I tried to detect it by a trap in the parent Bash script but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: `exit` is not guaranteed to work, you should instead use `EXIT`

Given that the POSIX standard does not define whether the `EXIT` trap should also be executed in case of a signal and given the fact that the Bourne Shell does not call the `EXIT` trap in the case you mention, it is obvious that you are entering *unspecified* behavior.